# Everytime I turn my computer on its in something called grub?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

So I've recently downloaded Ubuntu and was dual running it beside windows, but I didn't like Ubuntu so I went to deleting it. Here are the steps I took

1. I deleted the Ubuntu driver in my driver setting
2. Made a recovery drive

I was following a instructions, and it told me to restart computer. So I did, and now I'm in this thing called grub and I have no idea how to get out of it. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall Your Windows Boot Loader From the Windows DVD / USB.

Use repair your computer option from windows installer then reboot.

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.